# Give an interval on which there exists a solution to the Cauchy Problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Our professor gave us the following theorem:

**Theorem**: Let $\alpha = min\left(a, \dfrac{b}{M}\right)$ where $M = max |f|$ is the maximum of $|f|$ on $I \times J$ where $I= [x_0 - a, x_0 +a], J = [y_0 - b, y_0 +b]$.
Then there exists a unique solution $\phi : I \rightarrow J$ f the Cauchy problem.

Now I encounter several problems when trying to understand this theorem:

- $\alpha$ is defined at the beginning but isn't used in the theorem
- $a$ is not defined
- $b$ is not defined

Now, using this theorem I am supposed to find the interval on which there exists a solution to the following Cauchy Problem:$y' = 2y^2-x; y(1) =1$

So the only informmations I know are $(x_0, y_0) = (1,1)$

Therefore I can't use the theorem.

Comment: It seems "Then there exists a unique solution $ϕ:I→J$" must continue saying "...in the interval $[x-\alpha,x+\alpha]$